# assertion failure with UIStepper

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am working on Xcode 4.3.3 and trying to use a UIStepper with interface builder. While trying to set minimum value = 0, maximum value = 10,000 , step value=100 and  current value = 5000. I am getting the following compile time error -

```
DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-1181/IBPlugin/WidgetIntegration/IBUIStepper/IBUIStepper.m:41
Details:  Assertion failed: aValue <= maximumValue && aValue >= minimumValue
Object:   <IBUIStepper: 0x40086e000>
Method:   -setValue:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a260>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:.............
```

I am clueless on what to do, got nothing on google. Anyone got similar error or any idea about it?

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the values?

Comment: I am using interface builder. Have set the values on utilities area.

Comment: tried to replicate it and got an `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255` error - sounds like a bug to me ... maybe doing it via code helps?

Comment: I have just started learning all of this, will take time to figure out how to do it with code. 
P.S. - i checked the xml file of storyboard, it shows all the values setup correctly. I doubt doing via code would help